# Numpy - User-defined data-type to built-in type

Tags: python, numpy

if I would like to supports casting from my data type to e.g. np.float:
`a = np.array([10, 20], np.float).astype(_float.myType) //cast np.float array to my np.myType array
 b = np.array(a).astype(np.float) //cast np.myType array to np.float array`
I have followed few examples on the internet( e.g. *[1](https://github.com/mwiebe/numpy_half/blob/master/numpy_half.c)), and I still have some problems. Am keep getting:
 
`ValueError: No cast function available.`

When it comes down to casting from my type to built-in type. Objects of `PyArray_ArrFuncs` have special attribute just for it `cast`. So if I want to cast from my type to np.float I should do.
`MyType_ArrFuncs.cast[NPY_FLOAT] = (PyArray_VectorUnaryFunc*)MyType_to_float;`

And of course register my type with 
`PyArray_RegisterDataType`, 
right?

Comment: Ok, so I figure out that `MyType_ArrFuncs.cast[NPY_FLOAT] = (PyArray_VectorUnaryFunc*)MyType_to_float;`, allows me this casting `b = np.array(a).astype(np.float32)`, not `b = np.array(a).astype(np.float) `